# How can hide request header and parameters for rest API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, networking

I am using laravel and Vue js.
In Vue js, I am requesting API using axios.
when I inspect and get request header and parameters in a browser and it is possible to request in Postman.
Everyone can request any APIs after login because it is possible to get header and parameters.

Comment: This is why some kind of back-end authentication with custom headers is crucial. Use a secret key and check it against some value you have in your env and have all endpoints come after authentication middleware.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hide this. However if you use **HTTPS**, the connection to your website is secure and no one in the middle can see it. The token is only visible to the user that it belongs to, so it poses no security risk as the user should have access to it.

Being able to inspect the requests sent is a **feature** of the browser and it is in no way related to your site.

Comment: If hacker register then he can get token and request api in site.